# Mocha and Chai fail insde a promise

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, es6-promise, isomorphic-fetch-api

I can't make Chai `expect` work in this simple example: Mocha's `done`function never seems to get called and assertions are simply ignored:

```
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

import 'isomorphic-fetch';

describe('Mocha and Chai', () => {
  it('tests chai expect inside a promise', (done) => {
    fetch('http://google.com').then(() => {
      const actual = 'test';
      const expected = 'expected';
      console.log(`'${actual}'' equals to '${expected}'?`, actual === expected);
      expect(actual).to.be.equals(expected);
      expect(actual).to.eventually.be.equals(expected);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Note that I have tried both, with and without `chai-as-promised`'s `eventually`.

This is the relevant output:

```
> mocha tools/testSetup.js "src/**/*.spec.js" --reporter progress

'test'' equals to 'expected'? false

  1) Mocha and Chai tests chai expect inside a promise:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

As you can see, the promise is working, I get my console output. But neither the `expect()`calls work nor the `done()`call does anything.

I am not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using `isomorphic-fetch` and the suggested `es6-promise`.

Comment: Try with `this.timeout(50000)` after `it()`

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The `done`callback is not actually needed. Mocha understand the scenario if you **return** the promise inside the `it()`block:

```
it('tests chai expect inside a promise', () => {
   return fetch('http://google.com').then(() => {
     const actual = 'test';
     const expected = 'expected';
     console.log(`'${actual}'' equals to '${expected}'?`, actual === expected);
     expect(actual).to.be.equals(expected);
     expect(actual).to.eventually.be.equals(expected);        
   });
});
```

Comment: What still bothers me is that if you miss returning the promise, the calls to `expect()` will simply pass without effect, giving false positives.